# Converting to responsive web design

Tags: html, css

I just finished my first page for a personal portfolio site. I am just a beginner when it comes to web development. I have set the width of my site to 1600 px, the same width of my background image.

What I wanted to do now is to convert the page to a responsive design. My only problem is that when I changed the width of the page to 100%, the position of my banner div is shifted to the left, instead of being in center.

here's a snippet of my code.

```
<body>

<div id="banner"> 
   <div class="container_12">
        <div class="grid_7 prefix_5" id="navbar">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html" title="Gelo Lopez">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="Project Management.html" title="Gelo Lopez Work" target="_blank">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://gelolopez.wordpress.com">Blog</a></li>
              <li><a href="/contact" title="Contact Gelo Lopez">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_10" id="bannertext">
            <h1>Hello!</h1>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <p>Hi, I am Gelo Lopez, an emerging digital marketing and PR Professional. I create stories for brands. I am the social media primmadonna</>
            <p id="bannerbutton"><img src="Assets/Images/bannerbutton.png" width="171" height="44" alt="Gelo Lopez Portfolio" /></p>
        </div>     
   </div>
   </div><!--end of banner-->
```

CSS:

```
body {
width: 100%;
color: #5a5959;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: "Lao UI"; 
}

/* sections*/
#banner {
background-image: url(../Images/Banner-background.png);
height:660px;
color: #fff;
font-size: 24px;
}
```

I am also using a 960 gs template for 12 columns. I decided to put the container_12 div under the id=banner in order to place the content in center of the page.

I hope somebody could help me

Comment: There is no "converting", you must design for it.  Read up on media queries.

Comment: Shifted to the right doesn't seem right? You can set your background to top center and that will fix the way your background looks. But your a long way from responsive design read up on media queries to get started.

Comment: Shifted to the right? Not left? Also `#banner` div should be by default 100%, so I assume problem with your background image. Just center that picture with `background-position` property.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was 'shifted to the left'. Will edit that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is that the background image is being cut off to the right, rather than the banner div being 'shifted to the right'.  The `<div>` as a block level element will fit it's parent, in this case it's the `body` which is set to 100% width.

If you're happy using CSS3, try adding `background-size: contain` to `#banner` which will scale your background image to the content area.

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/LCFun/

Comment: Thank you David. Tried it and it fit the width; however, my problem is on the height: as the width changes, the height also changes, I found out. IS there a way around this?

Comment: That's because it's scaling to it's container size.  If you scaled the width but not the height, the image would be out of proportion.  If you want to keep the image the original height, you'll probably want to keep it's original width too, in which case just use `background-position: top center' as others have suggested in comments to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to play around with [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) CSS tag. You can try putting in the extra line of CSS Code:

```
background-position: top left;
```

Also, since you're talking about it being a responsive site, you'll probably be aware that your background may not fill a screen size which you didn't design for. You'll probably need to repeat the background, or fix it... it's really according to your needs. Read up on Background repeat here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp